# HTML 5 - Do I need to declare DOCTYPE on includes and pages with decorator

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

I'm using Struts 2 and am working through my pages to make them HTML 5 compliant.

All pages are using just a single decorator jsp which is declared in the `decorators.xml`

The `decorator.jsp` includes as the first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Do I need to declare the first line on the pages (specified in `struts.xml`) as `<!DOCTYPE html>` on these?

If yes, do I also need to do the same for any `<s:include />`ed pages?

Comment: How about just start your app and navigate to some page to see if doctype is there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DOCTYPE` declaration should be the first line of the HTML document rendered by the result. You can also place space characters, comments, or [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character before the `DOCTYPE`. See [Conformant documents in the HTML syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#conformant-html). Pages are decorated mostly in the head or body of the document but a `DOCTYPE` should be before these tags and before any tag. You place `DOCTYPE` on every page at the first line, either included or manual, and then use this page with decorator. The `DOCTYPE` declaration should be rendered only once per HTML document, you shouldn't include it with every page that is `<s:include/>`-ed in the main page.